# Upper and lower bounds of a 2-3-4 tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am to find the upper and lower boundaries for the height of a 2-3-4 tree with n nodes. Frankly I have no clue how to start. Is there a formula for this? I would appreciate any help and thanks!

Comment: Show a bit of research or some sort of honest attempt.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja Thanks, I hadn't thought of that idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worst case, every node has exactly 2 sons, thus you need to solve:

```
2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^h >= n
```

Finding the minimal `h` that satisfies the conditions gives you the height of the "worst case" 2-3-4 tree.

Repeat the process with 4 sons per node to get the best case height.